# Showing data in Visual Studio Code as HEX code while debugging a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode-debugger

Is there an easy way to switch to see the data in hex in debug mode in flutter? I have a lot of UInt8 fields and the debugPrint method is not a good solution for me. Normally I see this:

[image]